# How to get the width and height of a string knowing its font size in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, size, font-size

I want to know if there is any way to determine the width and height of a string depending on the font name and font size used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`sizeWithFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a) method. That should be helpful. Depending on what your exact needs are, you can choose any one of the sister methods too.

Comment: Thanks for your replies...but the width I am getting is quite large.Larger than  the real width

Comment: Can you add the code snippet that you are using and the length you are getting?

Comment: Oh..that was a small mistake.Working correctly now...But this method works if we want to show the text in one line.What if the number of lines is more than 1.

Comment: Have you tried using the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` method?

Comment: No...I have never used it before.Can you please explain in detail

Comment: It's basically the same as before except in this case you pass in one more argument which is a `CGSize` structure. Since for multiples to exist, it must have a specified width. You create the a `CGSize` with that width. Set the height to a big value in case you want to know the exact height.

Comment: Got it...Thanks for your valuable help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can  use

```
– sizeWithFont:  
– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:  
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:  
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:  
– sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
```

Take a look at here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html